# How would one duplicate the behavior of poll for POLLPRI in mio?

Tags: io, rust, epoll

I have a driver that emits a `POLLPRI` event when new data is ready since the device is always readable (last data).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since mio use edge mode there is no need to register `EPOLLPRI`, these event will be reported anyway. You can just call [`is_priority()`](https://docs.rs/mio/0.7.11/mio/event/struct.Event.html#method.is_priority) on event, this of course only work when when the feature is available.