# How would one duplicate the behavior of poll for POLLPRI in tokio?

Tags: unix, events, rust, rust-tokio

I've found [How would one duplicate the behavior of poll for POLLPRI in mio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55277780/how-would-one-duplicate-the-behavior-of-poll-for-pollpri-in-mio/55278666) which provides how to do it on an old version of mio. But that method doesn't seem to work anymore. `Ready`/`UnixReady` doesn't exist in mio anymore.

Comment: there is probably zero chance you can do that, POLLPRI is very os specific and tokio is not OS specific.

Comment: Can I do it with Mio?

Comment: see my update answer you linked